# Protobuf parsing from tcp raw data

Tags: protocol-buffers

i am trying to decode a proto data from a request. The request is protobuf request over tcp. I captured these datas from the app. The problem is i can not decode/parse these datas for reusing them.

Here is a original data ( its raw hex stream ) 2000005c000000080db0020000100218800148022080042a4182203e0a3c62756d626c655f6d6f62696c655f6c616e64696e677c323a30306535653766312d653766312d663165362d653662662d6266343032306132313130613800

Here is a modified ( deleted some hex stream datas manually )
0a 3c 62 75 6d 62 6c 65 5f 6d 6f 62 69 6c 65 5f 6c 61 6e 64 69 6e 67 7c 32 3a 30 30 65 35 65 37 66 31 2d 65 37 66 31 2d 66 31 65 36 2d 65 36 62 66 2d 62 66 34 30 32 30 61 32 31 31 30 61

(Decoded data ----> 1   string  bumble_mobile_landing|2:00e5e7f1-e7f1-f1e6-e6bf-bf4020a2110a )

I tried python modules and this app https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app

The problem is its not decoding data successfully

Do you know how can i decode this and other datas without proto schema?

I tried decoding protobuf data without its original schema but i did not success. Wondering if anyone know how to decode kind of datas without original schema?

Comment: It's a bit of a guess, but looks like your raw data has a 8-byte header. If you cut that off, decoding the result has fields 1,2,3,4,5,7, and 9. Field 5 is a sub-message that includes the string you show above. You didn't say anything about where you got the data, so the header is a mystery.

Comment: I captured these datas myself, All of these requests and responses are like in the screenshot https://i.imgur.com/U5VMTsl.png These requests are protobuf over tcp, so no headers for requests. Also tried to decompile apk and find the decoder methods but failed.

Comment: Also here is the first data https://justpaste.it/dg4zg and screenshot https://i.imgur.com/SixSAeI.png

Comment: You're welcome by the way. I meant the OS, hardware, and software environment that produced the data. Details of how the protobuf made it onto the TCP stream are important: code or at least libraries being called. There are many ways a TCP stream can end up with extra data on it that you aren't necessarily expecting. What we can say for sure is that the first 8 bytes are not protobuf data because decoding yields a field number of zero. Conventional protobuf definitions never use zero as a field number. When we delete those bytes, decoding produces 7 fields that look like valid data.